# Network Router UI Simulators

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

Just sharing a site I found that could potentially be useful, not just here on Ask Different, but pretty much anywhere if you need to assist someone troubleshooting a network issue and need to see the modem/router interface.

- [Linksys UI Simulators](http://ui.linksys.com/) (http://ui.linksys.com/)
- [TP Link UI Simulators](https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/emulator/) (https://www.tp-link.com/us/support/emulator/)

If anyone knows of any other resources like this for any other vendors, feel free to post!

Comment: What do you think about adding the "canonical-questions" tag to this?  I was going to do it but then thought I'd ask what others think about that first.

Comment: @fsb Sure.  I was just posting this with the intention of helping folks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more:

- [Belkin device simulators](http://ui.belkin.com) (http://ui.belkin.com)
- [DD-WRT demo](https://router-firmware-test.gamma.nu/DD-WRT/index-2.html) (https://router-firmware-test.gamma.nu/DD-WRT/index-2.html)
- [DrayTek device live demos](https://www.draytek.com/products/live-demo/) (https://www.draytek.com/products/live-demo/)
- [NetComm device emulators](https://support.netcommwireless.com/emulators) (https://support.netcommwireless.com/emulators)
- [Netis device emulators](http://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/emulators.html) (http://www.netis-systems.com/Suppory/emulators.html)

In addition, the [Setup Router](https://setuprouter.com) (https://setuprouter.com) site is also a useful source of router setup guides, etc.

Comment: Nice find!  So many times I found myself reading poorly written manuals to try and walk folks through the web interface of a router to fix an issue.